# Python __pow__ magic method overwritten in __init__ not called with **

Tags: python, magic-methods, setattr

I'm using Python 3.9.12, trying to dynamically overwrite instance methods on instance creation in **init** for a class (class A) from another class (class B), but getting unexpected results when doing this for the **pow** magic method.  The overwrite seems to work, but it is not recognized as a magic method.  How to allow the new `__pow__` method (from class B) to be called in `a**2`?

For example, defining

```
class A(object):
    
    def __init__(self, **kwdict):
        ## Set the '__pow__' method in class A from class B
        new_method_name = '__pow__'
        new_method = getattr(B, new_method_name)
        setattr(self, new_method_name, new_method.__get__(B, self.__class__))

    def __pow__(self, other):
        print("Running __pow__ from class A definition.")

        
        
class B(object):
    
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def __pow__(self, other):
        print("Running __pow__ from class B definition.")
```

and running

```
a = A()
a**2
```

gives the output

```
Running __pow__ from class A definition.
```

from the original class A method, while running the method directly

```
a.__pow__(2)
```

gives the output

```
Running __pow__ from class B definition.
```

from the new class B method.

**Question:** How to return the class B output in both cases?

Comment: Why isn't class A a subclass of class B?

Comment: Dunders are looked up on the class, not the instance.